# Android getting result of AsyncTask in main Activity and add views to XML layout outside onCreate method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I'm trying to obtain a list of videos from `Youtube` to be displayed on my `Activity`.
I've created the main activity `MediaActivity.java` with two methods, `onCreate` and `getResult` which is called from the `onPostExecute` method in the `AsyncTask` class.
Here is the `MediaActivity` code:

```
    public class MediaActivity extends Activity {
    YoutubeConnect youtubeRequest = new YoutubeConnect(); 
    ViewGroup media;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        youtubeRequest.execute();
        setContentView(R.layout.media);
        media = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.layout.media);

    }

    public void getResult(String result) throws JSONException {


        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("feed");
        JSONArray the_json_array = jsonObj2.getJSONArray("entry");

        int size = the_json_array.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            //get all infos
               [...]
            LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
            main.setOrientation(0);
            main.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //thumb
            WebView thumb = new WebView(this);
            thumb.loadUrl(video_thumb);
            main.addView(thumb);

            LinearLayout right = new LinearLayout(this);
            right.setOrientation(1);
            right.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //title
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(video_title);
            right.addView(title);

            //description
            TextView description = new TextView(this);
            description.setText(video_description.substring(100)+"...");
            right.addView(description);

            //views
            TextView views = new TextView(this);
            views.setText("Views: "+video_views);
            right.addView(views);

            main.addView(right);                

            this.media.addView(main);
        }


     }      

}
```

This is my custom `AsyncTask` class code:

```
 public class YoutubeConnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public YoutubeConnect() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try {
             String APIurl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=author&alt=json";
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(APIurl);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                return builder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MediaActivity mainthread = new MediaActivity();
        try {
            mainthread.getResult(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




 }
```

This is the log:

```
 05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2696)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:374)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:166)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at wachipi.palio.MediaActivity.getResult(MediaActivity.java:47)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at wachipi.palio.YoutubeConnect.onPostExecute(YoutubeConnect.java:41)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at wachipi.palio.YoutubeConnect.onPostExecute(YoutubeConnect.java:1)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-17 11:01:26.383: E/AndroidRuntime(2687):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Before various attempt the `setContenView` and `ViewGroup` lines were inside the `getResult` method, but it gave me other errors. I've also tried to use the debugger but it gives me error `"source not found"`, I think something is missing in my installation.
I really can't understand why it throws this error and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That exception probably comes from you instantiating a new `MediaActivity` instead of using the `Activity` instance from which you started the thread:

```
MediaActivity mainthread = new MediaActivity();//don't do this
```

Instead pass a reference of your `MediaActivity` in the `YoutubeConnect` task and use that reference to call `getResult`:

```
private MediaActivity activityRef;

public YoutubeConnect(MediaActivity activityRef) {
     this.activityRef = activityRef;
}
```

and in the `onPosteExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        activityRef.getResult(result); // you should have some ckecks to see if the activity is still available.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then to make a new `YoutubeConnect` task:

```
    YoutubeConnect youtubeRequest;
    ViewGroup media;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.media);
        youtubeRequest = new YoutubeConnect(this); 
        youtubeRequest.execute();
        media = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.layout.media);
    }
```

Also, with this:

```
media = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.layout.media);
```

You're searching for a `View` in the current layout by a layout file name and not an `id`. It should be like this:

```
media = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.view_id_from_the_layout);
```